# Unexpected output from NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdate

when i try log out the current date i get date different from actual date :

NSLog(@"date %@",[NSDate date]);

output 2012-04-25 23:59:28 +0000

my machine time 2012-04-26 2:02 AM

any one knows how to fix this ? thanks

**EDIT**

here's what i get when using nsdataformatter

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
NSDate *date =[formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithString:@"2012-04-26 01:00:00"]];
 NSLog(@"date %@",date);
```

output : 2012-04-25 23:00:00 +0000 
confusing !

Comment: Why the heck are you using `stringWithString`??

Comment: You're not using NSDateFormatter to format the date!!!!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting date from \[NSDate date\] off by a few hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to fix.  NSLog is outputting the date in GMT/UTC.  If you want it in your local timezone, you need to use NSDateFormatter.

Comment: @mbg1987 -- Show us where you tried to use NSDateFormatter to format the date.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you print the Local time and GMT time

```
  // gmt
  NSTimeZone *aTimeZone1 = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
  NSInteger aTimeInterval1 = -[aTimeZone1 secondsFromGMTForDate: [NSDate date]];
  NSLog(@"GMT: %@", [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: aTimeInterval1 sinceDate: [NSDate date]]);

  // local
   NSTimeZone *aTimeZone2 = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
   NSInteger aTimeInterval2 = [aTimeZone2 secondsFromGMTForDate: [NSDate date]];
   NSLog(@"Local: %@", [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: aTimeInterval2 sinceDate: [NSDate date]]);
```

**AND**

If you want to use NSDateFormatter then, how about trying this :

```
  NSDateFormatter *aDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [aDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
  [aDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
  NSLog(@"GMT: %@", [aDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);

  [aDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
  NSLog(@"Local: %@", [aDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```