# NSDatePicker showing the wrong time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm using a UIDatePicker and when it selects 7:00am it displays in a UILableView 6:00am. How can i set the UIDatePicker to display the right time ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting date from \[NSDate date\] off by a few hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];

self.datePicker.locale = locale;
```

set this in your program

Answer (score 2):

I think your date picker might be picking the right date, but your **label** does not display it correctly. Use an `NSDateFormatter` to set the correct locale and format the date as desired.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale]; 
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle; // e.g.
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

myLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:dateFromPicker];
```

Answer (score 0):

set your Label text value inside the

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   // You have the selected row, update the text field.
}
```