# NSString to NSDate returns wrong date

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I try to convert my `NSString` to `NSDate` object, but `NSDateFormatter` returns me a strange value.

Here is code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"]; 
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012-08-15 00:00"];
[dateFormat release];
```

`date` value is `2012-08-14 21:00 +0000`. It is 3 hours difference between `NSString` value and `NSDate` value. I think I've missed something, but I don't know what.

Comment: What if you try `NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012-08-14 24:00"];`?

Comment: @mavrick3 no, dateformatter returns nil

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting date from \[NSDate date\] off by a few hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours)

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with the timezone ... are you 3 hours away from utc ?

Comment: Yes, I live 3 hours away from utc

Comment: I use NSLocal to generate the accurate time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what i use:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"]; 

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012-08-15 00:00:00 +0000"];
NSLog(@"\n\n  DATE: %@ \n\n\n", date);
```

The `+0000` is timezone, so make sure you use your timezone, like `+0400`.

Edit:
If you can't change the string, you can use this code to do it:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"]; 
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012-08-15 00:00"];
```

Comment: Unfortunately I receive this value from web server, and it returns me string without +0000

Answer (score 0):

As i knew NSDate holds Grinwich time, so if you are in Moscow time zone, everything is wright

Answer (score 0):

In objective c for NSDate if you did not set the setTimeZone, NSDate will take default timezone as localTimeZone. so if you need to get the exact date which you give as NSString string format, you need to setTimeZone as UTC. Follow the sample code, I guess it will be helpful for you.

```
NSDateFormatter *loacalformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[loacalformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *localDate =[loacalformatter dateFromString:@"2012-08-15 00:00"];
NSLog(@"localDate :%@",localDate);


NSDateFormatter *UTCformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[UTCformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[UTCformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *UTCDate =[UTCformatter dateFromString:@"2012-08-15 00:00"];
NSLog(@"UTCDate :%@",UTCDate);
UTCDate :2012-08-15 00:00 +0000 (GMT+00:00)
```

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in the comments, if the date you receive is UTC then you need to convert it to your local timezone.  Apple recommend you always use a properly configured NSDateFormatter when displaying dates, to handle localisation issues.

Here's some example code for turning an NSDate into an NSString:

```
NSDate *date = // initialised elsewhere

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
dateFormat.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
dateFormat.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
dateFormat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;    
dateFormat.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *dateAsString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```