# NSDate early by 1 hour?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am using the following code to set a date object:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date];
        [components setHour: 18];
        [components setMinute: 00];
        [components setSecond: 00];

        reminderDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];
```

However, when I NSLog reminderDate I get the following output:

```
Time: 2012-08-29 17:00:00 +0000
```

Which is **early by one hour**, can anyone explain what it is I need to do in order to store the correct date in **reminderDate**?

Thanks,

Tysin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting date from \[NSDate date\] off by a few hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your time zone? If you notice, the date that you print has +0 time zone, so if your time zone is +1 is all correct.

Comment: I've tried setting the timezone to use my local time zone with NSTimeZone localTimeZone but there was no change..Currently I am in British Summer Time which is GMT + 1

Comment: This means that the date in the log is correct, since it is displayed without the time zone, hence the +0000

Comment: The date in the log isn't correct, if I do this: NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [NSDate date]); the date printed is also 1 hour earlier than it should be..

Comment: Log is correct, NSLog always print with time zone +0. If you time zone is different, convert the date to time zone +0.