# Calculating actual day's midnight date

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting date from [NSDate date] off by a few hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours)

I want to calculate the actual day's midnight time using the actual day's date here is the code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSString *todayStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 12:59 PM",[formatter stringFromDate:today]];
NSLog(@"%@",todayStr);
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *midNight = [formatter dateFromString:todayStr];
NSLog(@"%@",midNight);
```

But the log I get is :

```
23/01/2013 12:59 PM
2013-01-23 10:59:00 +0000
```

Why does `midNight` isn't the actual midnight and why does it have a different format from `formatter`?

Answer (score 1):

The midnight you calculated with date formatter takes the localization into account.

So, you are living in a UTC+2 timezone.

You can add a 'Z' for UTC.

See more at http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: I don't get where to add the 'Z'

Comment: 1994-11-05T13:15:30Z is UTC time, while 1994-11-05T13:15:30 is local time.

Comment: So how should I modify my code?

Comment: I don't see what else you want or anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This calculates midnight for your local timezone.

```
NSDate *d = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:d];
d = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:d];
NSLog(@"%@", dateStr);
```

prints 23/01/2013 12:00 AM

Comment: You might want to add NSEraCalendarUnit just for completeness.

Comment: I'm getting `2013-01-22 22:00:00 +0000` as date for `d`...

Comment: Good point Fabian. I updated the code.

Comment: moray95: When you log the NSDate, it prints in UTC time. Use NSDateFormatter to print it for your local timezone.

Comment: moray95: You're already doing it in the initial question. I expanded the code also.