# Converting string to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I am trying to use NSDateFormatter to convert the following string to an NSDate: **2013-08-19 7:00 AM**.

However, the following NSDate is created: `2013-08-19 04:00:00 +0000`. The hour is wrong.

My code is below. I don't know what I am doing incorrectly.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];
NSString *string = @"2013-08-19 7:00 AM";
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're not specifying a time-zone. What time-zone are you on?

Comment: @LuisCien I didn't realize that mattered. I want to create two date objects (such as for 7 AM and for 11 AM) and count the seconds between the two times.

Comment: I had this "problem" before too. Not really a problem, but you have no time zone set. NSDate does not include the time zone.

Comment: @Jamie Should I set it to the local timezone?

Comment: Yes. If that's where you're getting the time from. It would be wherever the time is coming from.

Comment: @JackHumphries There is no need to set the formatter's timezone if you want the local timezone - that is the default behavior.

Comment: @JackHumphries When you log an `NSDate` object it is always logged in UTC (+0000). That is normal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting date from \[NSDate date\] off by a few hours](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8466744)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to use a 24-hour format for the hours *and* an AM/PM indicator, and that just won't work. Change your line:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];
```

to this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
```

and you'll find that your code now works.

Answer (score -2):

The reason why you see "+0000" means that the OS is converting your time string to UTC. To solve this you just have to set your local time-zone.

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = YOUR_LOCAL_TIMEZONE;
```

Also, to print your date in your local settings you can use `NSDateFormatter`'s:

```
localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is the correct: `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];`

Comment: It's still returning 4 AM.

Comment: @LuisCien No, the OS is not converting any string. The issue is simple - when you log an `NSDate` object, the `description` method is called on the `NSDate`. The implementation of this method is to return the date as a string in UTC time. None of this has anything to do with the actual parsing of the string into an `NSDate` using the `NSDateFormatter` (which assumes locale time by default).

Comment: The reason he sees +0000 is that NSLog of an NSDate always returns UTC.

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light on me :)