# get date from string "2014-10-08T15:09:19+05:30"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get date from this string 2014-10-08T15:09:19+05:30. My code is

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014-10-08T15:09:19+05:30"]);
```

but o/p is 2014-10-08 09:39:19 +0000

expected is 2014-10-08 15:09 PM

saw other threads also and tried with timezone as suggested in others but not able to get the correct date.

Comment: Why do you expect `2014-10-08 15:09 PM`? That's not the format used by the `NSDate description` method.

Comment: You **do** have the correct date.  Those two dates are the same since I assume you live in India.

Comment: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];
someone just answered with that i came to know. thank u.

Comment: yes @borrrden by just seeing that time i was thinking that's wrong. now i got it. thanks anyways.

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting date from \[NSDate date\] off by a few hiurs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your code is equivalent to:

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014-10-08T15:09:19+05:30"];
NSLog(@"%@", [date description]);
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and `[NSDate description]` generates a string in the GMT timezone, which leads to your confusion.