# iOS NSDate() returns incorrect time

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am trying to get current date in Swift using `NSDate()`. When I create breakpoint and stop application, I can see that there is 3 hours difference with devices' system time. Application is running on real iPhone. How to fix this?

I also wrote the following in App Delegate to be sure:

```
NSTimeZone.setDefaultTimeZone(NSTimeZone(name: "Europe/Kiev")!)
```

But it still does not work.

Comment: Post code first, that would be easy to solve your Problem.

Comment: Here's code: `let currentDate = NSDate()`

Comment: Another note: device's time is form Kiev, but I am located in Slovakia. But time difference is only 1 hour, not 3 hours, so I don't think it is connected.

Comment: Show how you determined the time was "wrong". Did you log the value? Look at it in the debugger? It was probably logged in UTC time.

Comment: If it is UTC time, there should be 2 hours difference. Kiev is in UTC+2 Zone

Comment: Perhaps (another) duplicate of [Getting date from NSDate date off by a few hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours) ?

Comment: You are right, but how to set time zone for debugger?

Comment: Can you set the time to GMT, then use +x for hours depending on time zone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't return the wrong time. It returns exactly the right time. NSDate doesn't have any timezone information. Right now, my computer and your computer will report the exact same time when we call NSDate ().

NSLog displays NSDate in UTC. That's just what it displays. So if we both call NSLog right now, your computer will log the same date and time as mine. Because it is the same date and time.

If you want to process an NSDate (for example, to display the date and time to a user) you use an NSCalendar. The NSCalendar translates between NSDate, which is the same everywhere in the world, to the values that you want to display in your user interface, which will be different in London or in Kiev. If I look on my watch right now, I will see a different time than you see on your watch, and that is what NSCalendar is there for.

Comment: How can I implement the calendar defined by a user on his device? Will not NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian always be?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the conversion for swift 3.0 :

```
func getCurrentLocalDate()-> Date {
    var now = Date()
    var nowComponents = DateComponents()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    nowComponents.year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: now)
    nowComponents.month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: now)
    nowComponents.day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: now)
    nowComponents.hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: now)
    nowComponents.minute = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: now)
    nowComponents.second = Calendar.current.component(.second, from: now)
    nowComponents.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")!
    now = calendar.date(from: nowComponents)!
    return now as Date
}
```

Comment: How to know TimeZone for every user in the world? Not always will be GMT?

Comment: Not solved: I can not get the user TimeZone. TimeZone.current.abbreviation() return a value, but when I used after TimeZone(abbreviation: my App crashes.

Comment: When I use "TimeZone.current.abbreviation()" this is the output -> Optional("GMT+2") ... (I do not understand anything)

Answer (score 1):

Also worth checking if your test device Date/Time is set to an older date.

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 2.2** this function did the trick for me:

```
func getCurrentLocalDate()-> NSDate {
    var now = NSDate()
    let nowComponents = NSDateComponents()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    nowComponents.year = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(NSCalendarUnit.Year, fromDate: now)
    nowComponents.month = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(NSCalendarUnit.Month, fromDate: now)
    nowComponents.day = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(NSCalendarUnit.Day, fromDate: now)
    nowComponents.hour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: now)
    nowComponents.minute = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: now)
    nowComponents.second = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(NSCalendarUnit.Second, fromDate: now)
    nowComponents.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
    now = calendar.dateFromComponents(nowComponents)!
    return now
}
```

If you want a different timezone you can change it directly, or even better, pass it as a function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Locale to get current time and date.

```
        let today = NSDate()
        let locale = NSLocale.current
        print("Time of today: \(today.description(with: locale))")
```

Answer (score 0):

This func returns Now in a current time zone.

```
func convertDate(date:Date) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    var comp = DateComponents()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    comp.year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date)
    comp.month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)
    comp.day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date)
    comp.hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date)
    comp.minute = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date)
    comp.second = Calendar.current.component(.second, from: date)
    comp.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
    var dateFromCalendar = Date()
    if let calendarDate = calendar.date(from: comp) {
        dateFromCalendar = calendarDate
    }
    return dateFromCalendar
}
```

To use:

```
    let now = Date()
    let convertedDate = convertDate(date: now)
```