# Calendar Components are Negative

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get Time interval in human readable format e.g. 20 minutes ago

I am getting the date as below from server (dates coming from server are past dates)

```
"2019-02-06T16:42:41.908Z"
```

And I am using below date formatter

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Now when I tried to get date components using below

```
let interval = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day,.hour, .minute], from: serverDate, to: Date())
```

I am getting minutes in negative as

```
(lldb) p interval.minute
(Int?) $R2 = -9
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here. Any idea or suggestion would be great.

Comment: `DateFormatter` doesn't support a relative format like `... ago`.

Comment: @vadian I am not trying to get ...ago from date format. I am trying to get minutes, hours from time interval which should be positive.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS The date you get is in the future. That's the only possibility I see. Or the time on your device is not set correctly.

Comment: This may not be the issue here, but the variable you are using in the definition of interval is 'serverDate' and the variable you created is called 'date'.

Comment: Save `Date()` to a variable, e.g. `let now = Date()` and when you get a negative interval, print all three values `p serverDate`, `p now` and `p interval`. It should be obvious then why the interval is negative.

Answer (score 2):

You are using method [dateComponents(_:from:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293176-datecomponents) which returns the difference between two dates. Depending on the order of the two dates, the difference can be negative.

For example:

```
let interval = Calendar.current.dateComponents([...], from: date1, to: date2)
```

will return a negative interval when `date1 > date2`.

When `date2` is `Date()`, that is, the current date, a negative value means date is in the future.

Comment: thanks for your answer. All dates coming from the server are past dates, not future dates. I am editing my question for the same.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I am not able to reproduce your result with the information you have given.

Comment: Thanks, I got the problem. Date() does not return correct time, So I used this link to resolve the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083756/ios-nsdate-returns-incorrect-time

Comment: `Date()` probably returns correct time. It's your server dates that probably have an incorrect timezone.