# NSDate() giving 3hrs behind of the current time while testing on iPhone

Tags: swift

How do I solve this issue? 
I'm storing NSDate() in a variable for my StepPedometer App.

CODE:  let date = NSDate();    println(date)                                         OUTPUT:  2015-07-03 14:33:02 +0000

Comment: You haven't shown any code or data. But most probably it is a duplicate of [Getting date from NSDate date off by a few hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours) (which is #1 in the "frequent" section of [nsdate]).

Comment: CODE:  let date = NSDate();    println(date)                                         OUTPUT:  2015-07-03 14:33:02 +0000

Answer (score 0):

When you `NSLog` a `NSDate` object, it will show it to you in GMT/UTC. That's what the `+0000` means. If you want to see it in your local time zone, use `NSDateFormatter`:

```
let date = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
println(formatter.stringFromDate(date))
```