# Convert 12 hr to 24

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm converting 12 hour date to 24 here, but it failed to get perfect time.
Here is code :

```
  NSString *dateStr = @"2016-08-12T04:10:14.915Z";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

and my final date is

```
2016-08-11 22:40:14 +0000
```

How ?

Comment: HH = 24 hour, hh = 12 hour, so try change `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

Comment: please see updated qun.

Comment: what teh issue u faced

Comment: i want to convert 04Hour(12Hr) to 16Hour(24Hr)

Comment: @Kabali, what makes you think that date (`"2016-08-12T04:10:14.915Z"`) is in 12h format?

Answer (score 0):

The NSDate object that you are getting is GMT. In France GMT -2, if I run your code I have a time of 02:10.

Am I correct assuming your GMT offset is -5:30 ?

> NSDate objects don't have time zones; they represent an absolute
>   moment in time. However, when you ask one for its description (by
>   printing it in an NSLog, e.g.), it has to pick a time zone. The most
>   reasonable "default" choice is GMT. If you're not in GMT yourself, the
>   date will seem to be incorrect, by the amount of your own offset.
>
> You should always use an NSDateFormatter, setting its timezone to
>   yours, before displaying a date.

Don't trust what NSLog or the debbuger are telling you about a NSDate.
use

```
NSString dateAsString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

to check your date :)

Comment: if you use a NSDateFormatter set to [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]] to print the date later on, you'll have it correctly setup at 04:10 :)

Comment: i already use localTimeZone in dateformate please see in question.

Comment: and if i use [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"] than it not convert my 04(12Hr) to 24Hr.

Comment: Yes, and there is no probleme with that. look at this thread for more answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours/38896078#38896078

Comment: i dont want to add GMT, i just want to conver 12 to 24 hr

Comment: instead of looking at you final date object, print it in a NSString with [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]; and you will see, all is fine :)