# Can not calculate the first day of the current month

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to calculate the `Date` (`NSDate`) instance that corresponds to the first day of the current month (I do not care about the time).

I am using this code (Swift 3):

```
let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

let today = Date()

var dateComponents = gregorian.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month], from: today)
dateComponents.day = 1

guard let firstDayOfTheMonth = gregorian.date(from: dateComponents) else { 
    return 
}
```

On the debugger, `today` gives me the correct value of `Date    2016-08-18 06:52:39 UTC`. However, `firstDayOfTheMonth` gives: `Date    2016-07-31 15:00:00 UTC`, that is, ***the last day of the previous month.***

Obviously I'm **off by one**, but can't figure out why.

What is worse, when I try to get the weekday, I get the correct value of 2 (Monday, for August 1st):

```
// Sun = 1, Mon = 2, Wed = 3, ...
guard let firstWeekDay = gregorian.dateComponents([.weekday], from: firstDayOfTheMonth).weekday else { 
    return 
}
```

...so, ***What's going on?***

Comment: The result is correct. `2016-07-31 15:00:00 UTC` is `2016-08-01` in *your timezone*. (NS)Dates are an absolute point in time without knowledge of a timezone. Printing a Date always uses UTC.

Comment: You are right; I checked this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8467038/433373) in the duplicate question, and as suggested printed the formatted dates to the console instead of watching them in the debugger. Now the first day of the month appears as "2016-08-01". I'm in JST (+0900).

Comment: Apart from the issue the recommended method to calculate the first day of the month is `rangeOfUnit(:startDate:interval:forDate:)` of `NSCalendar`